# Display photo preview in edit or view form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I currently have an inventory list with a lookup column containing photos that I would like to preview when editing or viewing. Currently the column has a link to the photo. Is there a way to display the preview in the form and or column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a HyperLink/Picture can be brought through as a Lookup Field.
What I have done in the past is create a WorkFlow in SP Designer that copy's the Picture link from the Lookup to the Main item. The Main list would need a Picture Column available to populate. Then this can be displayed in a view or Display Form.